# How to control individual functions in excel chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm not sure this is the right place, but I'll give it a try.

I have this graph:

[image]

All of the functions' X Axis were given the same data (12,24,36,48), except `ROULETTE` and `TOURNAMENT` which were also given (60) for the X axis.

Why aren't the `NORMAL` bars located on the place they should on the X axis?

For example, the 1st bar (from the left), should be a little more to the right. The others should move to the left.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Column (and Bar) charts don't work like that. They assume the x-axis (or y-axis in the case of a bar) are "Categories". Categories are not numbers, they are just categorizations of the data, like Car Models, or City names, or Student names. In your case, your categories are "12", "24", "36", and "48"; which, of course are totally unhelpful as a category.

The x-axis numbering you see is actually coming through from your scatter-plot/line chart and has nothing to do with the column chart at all.

As for a solution... it's a little ugly, but for the data used for the Column Chart, you could make an excel column numbered 1 through 70 (to match your x-axis min and max) and then stick your numbers that represent the height of the bar in the next column for the appropriate category (for instance 1-11 would be empty, 12 would be "50", 13-23 would be empty, 24 would be 115, etc.) Like I said.. ugly.

Also, you may want to reassess your choice of a column chart to plot (x,y) type data. Perhaps make "Normal" the same type of chart as the others, but change the line thickness and/or markers to distinguish from the others.